# Using Twitter API with Python (geocode)

Tags: python, json, twitter, geocode

How could I make the following call in Python?  Pseudocode version:

```
jsonTwitterResponse = twitter.get(up to max of 3 
                      tweets within 3km of longitude: 7, latitude: 5)
print jsonTwitterResponse
```

It looks like the [geocode](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search) API is what I need.  I have no idea how to actually code this up though.  How would I do the above in actual code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a sample *geocode* request:

```
import urllib, json, pprint

params = urllib.urlencode(dict(q='obama', rpp=10, geocode='37.781157,-122.398720,1mi'))
u = urllib.urlopen('http://search.twitter.com/search.json?' + params)
j = json.load(u)
pprint.pprint(j)
```

The full Twitter REST API is described here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api
Also, Twitter has a [location search FAQ](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/places/finding-tweets-about-places) that may be of interest.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Raymond Hettinger's answer, I'd like to mention that you can also use a query like `"near:Amsterdam within:5km"` if you don't want to work with actual coordinates.

Example: http://search.twitter.com/search?q=near:Amsterdam%20within:5km

Comment: Nice. I didn't know about that option :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think this method might've been added more recently:

```
import urllib, json, pprint

params = urllib.urlencode(dict(lat=37.76893497, long=-122.42284884))
u = urllib.urlopen('https://api.twitter.com/1/geo/reverse_geocode.json?' + params)
j = json.load(u)
pprint.pprint(j)
```

Documentation: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/geo/reverse_geocode